# css class is not visible if created using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

```
function get_files(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_files.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#insideT").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

get_files.php

```
$dir = 'uploads/';
$a = scandir($dir);
$b = count($a);
$res = '';
for ($x = 2; $x < $b; $x++) {
    $res.= "<div class='filePass'>";
    $res.= $a[$x];
    $res.= "</div>";
}
echo $res;
```

css works:

```
.filePass:hover{
    background-color:#e1e1e1;
}
```

but js doesn't work:

```
$('.filePass').click(function(){
alert ('323');
});
```

If I "manually"  create `filePass` class - everything works.

If the class is created using the above `get_files`, css works, but js doesn't.

JS Console in Chrome says that `filePass` exists.

Any help ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: When are you assigning the click event to the `filePass` div? If it's before the ajax success callback, it won't work. Put it after the `$("#insideT").html(result);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is event delgation using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the dynamically generated button.

```
$("#insideT").on('click','.filePass',function(){
    alert ('323');
});
```

Where `#insideTis` the closest parent element, you can use `document` or `document.body` also as a selector!

*Syntax:*

```
 $(elements).on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
function get_files(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_files.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#insideT").html(result);
            $('.filePass').click(function(){
                alert ('323');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

or

```
function get_files(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_files.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#insideT").html(result);
        }
    });
}
$('.filePass').on('click',function(){
    alert ('323');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i asume that the js function is located in your onload function, in which case it is normal that it should not be applied anymore. The onload event is already finished.

you should add this function in the success callback from your ajax call as well.

```
function foo(){
    $('.filePass').click(function(){
        alert ('323');
    });
}

function get_files(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "get_files.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
          $("#insideT").html(result);
          foo();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
function get_files(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_files.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#insideT").html(result);
        }
    });
} 

$('.filePass').on('click',function(){
    alert ('323');
});
```